# Present a published paper on a scientific conference?

Tags: conference

I submitted a paper to a scientific conference, which was not yet published at that time. In the meantime, my paper has been published in a journal.

But in the last days I received the confirmation that my article was accepted for this conference.
The website for this conference states that authors are invited to submit their article to a number of journals after presentation. I have read in the case of other other conferences that already published articles are not accepted. Unfortunately, the conference website does not provide any further information.

Now my question is: am I allowed to present an already published paper at a conference?

Comment: This is very field-dependent. Please specify.

Comment: The organizers of the conference would probably be the best source of info on what they will accept.

Comment: @user151413 Economics/Finance

Comment: @TobKel Edit into the question, please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This depends on your community and the conference, but I would definitely ask the conference program chairs about this *as soon as possible*. If the conference is like many Computer Science conferences, where the proceedings count as archived, peer-reviewed publications, you may have already violated academic norms by submitting the same work to a journal while the work was still being reviewed for the conference (a double submission). In this case the conference PC chairs will be able to advise you what to do (most likely either withdraw the conference or the journal submission).

On the other hand, if this conference is a more traditional conference that focuses on *presenting* research rather than publishing papers, this may not be a problem at all. Still, a conversation with the PC chairs will bring clarity.